# Cant connect to AWS Aurora cluster endpoint but can access Writier instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a MySql Aurora cluster setup on AWS. For the last few weeks I have had all of my apps pointing to an instance endpoint, and it has been working fine. Yesterday, however, I started getting errors on inserts/updates saying that the instance was in ReadOnly mode and couldnt be updated.

Apparently the Reader/Writer endpoints can change and what I am really supposed to do is point to the cluster endpoint, which will route the request appropriately. I have tried pointing directly to that cluster endpoint, but it always fails. The error message is fairly generic, telling me to check my username/password, make sure I am not blocked by a firewall, and all of the normal default solutions.

My Cluster is in a VPC, but the Subnets assigned to the cluster are public (they are routed through Internet Gateway).

The ready/writer instances have the same Security Group and VPC configuration. I can connect to the Reader instance (Read Only) but not the Writer instance.

Any idea what else I could look for? Most forums say that I need to check my Routing Tables or security groups, but from what I can tell that are all open to all traffic (I realize that is a bad configuration, I am just trying to get this working). Is there anything else that I should be checking?

Thanks

**Update**
I can Telnet in to the Reader instance, but not the Writer instance. They are in the same VPC, and both use the public subnet as far as I can tell.

**Update 2**
My Lambda functions that are in the same VPC as my RDS can access the Cluster endpoint, so I guess its just a problem getting outside. I thought that would be resolved by having a public subnet in the VPC but it doesnt seem to work for that endpoint.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience, definitely a helpful read  :-D

Comment: @ox Not really. When updates occur or there is a reason for failover, the Readonly and Writable instances tend to switch. If I have a situation where I cant access the current instance from my local box, I force a failover from the RDS console. The writer and reader typically switch after a failover. It solves the problem in a very unsexy way. It isnt an issue in production or QA environments because code deployed to the VPC has access to both reader and writer. Now its just annoying to have to cause a failover once a month.

Comment: @bsayegh Is there anything else you'd like as part of this post?

Comment: Did you check your DB Subnet Group of your AWS cluster? By default when you create a Aurora RDS, the DB Subnet Group is automatically created and it includes ALL subnets (public and private) of the VPC the Aurora RDS is created in.  Thus your DB instances may end up in public or private subnet. Click on your DB instance (NOT cluster) and check the 'Connectivity & Security' tab, you should see the 'Subnet Group' and 'Subnets', confirm that the 'Subnet Group' only has public subnets and your 'Subnets' are only public subnets.

Answer (score 1):

Merely having public subnets would not be enough, you need to explicitly enable public accessibility for your db instances. Public Accessibility is an instance level setting, and you need to turn that ON on all your instances in the cluster. Given your symptoms, I suspect if you have enabled public access on one of your instances and not on some of the others. You can check the same via CLI using the `describe-db-clusters` API and filtering or searching for `PubliclyAccessible`. Here is an example:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --region us-west-2 --output json --query 'DBInstances[?Engine==`aurora`].{instance:DBInstanceIdentifier, cluster:DBClusterIdentifier, isPublic:PubliclyAccessible }'
[
    {
        "instance": "karthik1",
        "isPublic": true,
        "cluster": "karthik-cluster"
    },
    {
        "instance": "karthik2",
        "isPublic": false,
        "cluster": "karthik-cluster"
    }
]
```

You modify an instance and enable public access on it using the `modify-db-instance` API.

Hope this helps.